# Getting feeds from Facebook groups using Graph API HTTP requests

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I would like to integrate my APP with some existing groups in Facebook.
So, for that, I would like to be able to read people's posts.

I have tried the following HTTP request to Facebook's graph API:

http://graph.facebook.com/v2.5/192992880732335

But it responds with the following:

```
{
   "error": {
      "message": "An access token is required to request this resource.",
      "type": "OAuthException",
      "code": 104,
      "fbtrace_id": "By+n1YSvvrI"
   }
}
```

How can I get an access token to a specific group?

Comment: The group need to be public and you need to us a user access token. If you are admin of the group you can also query non public groups

Answer (score 0):

It is pretty ease to get all the feeds from that group.
Just add the access token from some user and your are done:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v2.5/192992880732335/feed?access_token=<ACCESS TOKEN>
```

To get the access token, it is just a matter of calling

```
FB.getAuthResponse().accessToken
```

after user's login.